# Is there a word for an example that is wrong?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for an example that is wrong?

That is, using an example in an argument that is either a misrepresentation or does not illustrate what the arguer suggests it does.

Is there a word for this kind of false example?

Comment: I don't know of a word specific to "bad examples," but "irrelevant" might work in this case.

Comment: Contradiction sounds like the term you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

For the "invalid argument" itself, I'm quite partial to...

> [**specious**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/specious) *- superficially plausible, but actually wrong*

And for the "invalid example" supporting what may in fact be a valid argument,...

> [**spurious**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/spurious) *- not being what it purports to be; false or fake*

As [this NGram for **argument**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spurious%20argument,specious%20argument&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,spurious%20argument;,c0;.t1;,specious%20argument;,c0), and [this one for **example**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spurious%20example,specious%20example&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,spurious%20example;,c0;.t1;,specious%20example;,c0) show, many others do the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think that **fallacy** fits really well here.

> a deceptive, misleading, or false notion, belief

You could use **illusion** too but many people associate that with magic/wizardry.

> an erroneous mental representation

The speaker was definitely committing an act of **prevarication**.

> a statement that deviates from or perverts the truth

But most people would just say **lie**.

Answer (score 1):

If the example was an honest attempt at refuting my position, I would simply point out how the example was ***flawed***:

> Your example is *flawed*, because it makes a false assumption.

If the example was a deliberate attempt to misrepresent my position, I would say that the example is a ***fabrication***.

> *fabricate*: to create or make up (something, such as a story) in order to trick people
>   (Source: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fabricate))

Answer (score 0):

I would say in my field that it is an invalid example. Nothing more fancy than that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that *sophistry*, meaning a clever but flawed argument, is applicable here.

Answer (score 0):

If your example is practicing an ["adherence to or persistence in an erroneous use of language, memorization, practice, belief, etc., out of habit or obstinacy"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mumpsimus), it is a mumpsimus

If your example is of "[Incorrect doctrine or opinions"](http://wiktionary.academic.ru/108651/cacodoxy), it is a cacodoxy

If they are making a point but failing or ignoring to address the topic, it is referred to as a 'ignoratio elenchi'